# Easy DB web front end

Tags: mysql, web-frontend

I'm looking to build a very simple web interface for someone. The user will have no knowledge of SQL. They will need the following functionality:

- Simple inserts/updates
- WHERE clause functionality (sorting, basically)
- Simple math computations (sum, total, perhaps some multiplication)
- Access to the front end via mobile (read-only mobile access is fine)
- Connection to MySQL DB

The database itself will be small (sixty "paper pages" of input data) and there will only be a max of two users at once. Security is always important on the web, but only public data is stored in the database. The DB and web front will be run off a home computer (probably inside a VM).

phpMyAdmin and similar tools require a bit more knowledge of DBs than the user has. SpagoBI reports would fit the bill but require some building to get things up. I was curious about [VFront](http://www.vfront.org/), [Xataface](http://xataface.com/wiki/about), and similar tools.

What is a free web front-end framework that meets these requirements and requires minimal build time?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the technology stack that you are going to use, but the ASP.NET [scaffolding](http://sampathloku.blogspot.gr/2014/04/scaffolding-with-aspnet-mvc-5.html) can help you build UI that is following the DB model quite fast. As you are going to use mysql you would probably not use asp.net though.

Comment: I have outdated HTML/CSS experience and little php/javascript experience. Does this scaffolding require building or extensive modification to get operational?

Comment: I added one link. Here is another http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview. it requires Microsoft hosting (IIS) if you are going to host it somewhere. it helps with the CRUD operations. the filters you would need to write. probably easy with Entity Framework or LINQ